# Помогите убрать значок синхронизации справа внизу экрана

Tags: windows-10

Перезапуск проводника не помогает (эта херня отображается даже в момент отключения проводника) и это не значок на панели, он поверх других приложений (даже игр, запущенных в полноэкранном). Даже при выключении компьютера, когда уже написано посредине "Завершение работы..." он отображается какое-то время.
Нажимаю комбинацию **Windows + L** для возврата к входу в систему и на этом значке появляется значок паузы вместо стрелок.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит попробовать такой вариант отключения сихронизации от microsoft:
Пуск (Start) --> Настройки (Settings) --> Учетные записи (Accounts) --> Синхронизация ваших параметров (Sync your settings). И там отключить все возможные виды синхронизации.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026102/windows-10-about-sync-settings

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего вы включили мгновенный повтор,чтобы его убрать нажмите ALT+Z и там можно будет отключить(работает на видеокартах от Nvidia)